# Refresh DataGrid in Parent Window when Child Window closes WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, parent-child, page-refresh

Hello I have a double mouse click event for my `DataGrid` in my `Parent` window which opens a `Child` window and populates some `Textboxes` and `Comboboxes`

I also have a Window Closing event for my `Child` window, which saves the changes made to the SQL Server database.

I am trying to have my `DataGrid` refresh when my `Child` window has been closed. Please help!

Parent Window DataGrid code:

```
    public partial class DataGrid_HBD : UserControl
{

    public DataGrid_HBD()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SearchButtons_Load();
        DataGridData();


        // 2 Seconds Timer before connecting to the Database.
        // This improves UI rendering on button click
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loading Data Grid
    /// </summary>
    public void DataGridData()
    {

            // Attemption to connect to SQL Server database and populate DataGrid with database tables. 
            try
            {
                string connectionString = ("Data Source=WINDOWS-B1AT5HC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CustomerRelations;Integrated Security=True;");
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

                // Review SQL queries for security vulnerabilities
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [hb_Disputes].[DSP_ID], [hb_disputes].[ACCOUNT], [Users].[TX_EMPLOYEE], [hb_CsrNames].[NM_USER], [hb_disputes].[CUST_NAME],[hb_disputes].[PREM_ADDR], [hb_status].[Status], [hb_disputes].[OPENED], [hb_disputes].[DEADLINE], [hb_disputes].[DATERSLVD], [hb_disputes].[PRMCAUSE], [hb_disputes].[RPTTYPE], [hb_ratetype].[RateType], [hb_Disputes].[FR_DT_FIRSTREV], [hb_Disputes].[FR_TS_LATESTUPD], [hb_Disputes].[COMMENT], [hb_Disputes].[FR_DSP_CLSF], [hb_Disputes].[FINADJ], [hb_Disputes].[CALLRSN], [hb_Disputes].[SECCAUSE], [hb_Disputes].[MTR], [hb_Disputes].[SERTYPE], [hb_Disputes].[FR_CUST_CNTCT], [hb_Disputes].[FR_WRK_REQ], [hb_Disputes].[FR_OPN_ERR], [hb_Disputes].[FR_SO_TP], [hb_Disputes].[FR_SO_DTLS], [hb_Disputes].[FR_SO_DT_WNTD], [hb_Disputes].[FR_SO_ISSD_BY], [hb_Disputes].[FR_CMMNT], DATEDIFF(day,[OPENED], [DEADLINE]) AS DaysOpen FROM [hb_disputes]" +
                    " LEFT JOIN [Users] ON [hb_disputes].[ASSGNTO] = [Users].[KY_USER_ID] LEFT JOIN [hb_CsrNames] ON [hb_disputes].[WFMUSER] = [hb_CsrNames].[KY_USER_ID] LEFT JOIN [hb_status] ON [hb_disputes].[STATUS] = [hb_status].[STSID] LEFT JOIN [hb_ratetype] ON [hb_disputes].[REV_CLS] = [hb_ratetype].[RTID] Where [hb_disputes].[STATUS]= 3 AND [Users].[TX_EMPLOYEE] = '" + Environment.UserName + "'", connection);
                // Review SQL queries for security vulnerabilities
                connection.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                connection.Close();

                dtGrid.DataContext = dt;

                // Focus in on line 1 of the data grid on UserControl load 
                // So it can be shown in the key information side column

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

    }

    private void dtGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        // User double clicks on DataGrid Row
        // Open new Window
        // Populate selected textboxes with selected datarow
        DataGrid gd = (DataGrid)sender;
        DataRowView row_selected = gd.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

        var windowToOpen = new Window1();

        if (gd != null)
        {
            // Textboxes
            windowToOpen.txt_RowRecrd.Text = row_selected["DSP_ID"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_acctnumber.Text = row_selected["ACCOUNT"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_analyst.Text = row_selected["TX_EMPLOYEE"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_custname.Text = row_selected["CUST_NAME"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_address.Text = row_selected["PREM_ADDR"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_Status.Text = row_selected["Status"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_DaysOpen.Text = row_selected["DaysOpen"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_revcls.Text = row_selected["RateType"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_WFMissuedBy.Text = row_selected["NM_USER"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_ReviewNotes.Text = row_selected["FR_CMMNT"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_ResolutionNotes.Text = row_selected["COMMENT"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.DatePicker_ScheduledFor.Text = row_selected["FR_SO_DT_WNTD"].ToString();



            // Date Open Parse is needed for ShortDate format.
            if (row_selected["OPENED"] != null)
            {
                DateTime dateTime;
                if (DateTime.TryParse(row_selected["OPENED"].ToString(), out dateTime))
                {
                    windowToOpen.txt_opened.Text = dateTime.ToShortDateString();
                }
                else
                {
                    windowToOpen.txt_opened.Text = ""; //assign default value
                }
            }

            // Deadline Parse is needed for ShortDate format.
            if (row_selected["DEADLINE"] != null)
            {
                DateTime dateTime;
                if (DateTime.TryParse(row_selected["DEADLINE"].ToString(), out dateTime))
                {
                    windowToOpen.txt_deadline.Text = dateTime.ToShortDateString();
                }
                else
                {
                    windowToOpen.txt_deadline.Text = ""; //assign default value
                }
            }

            // Date Resolved Parse is needed for ShortDate format.
            if (row_selected["DATERSLVD"] != null)
            {
                DateTime dateTime;
                if (DateTime.TryParse(row_selected["DATERSLVD"].ToString(), out dateTime))
                {
                    windowToOpen.txt_DateResolved.Text = dateTime.ToShortDateString();
                }
                else
                {
                    windowToOpen.txt_DateResolved.Text = ""; //assign default value
                }
            }
            windowToOpen.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

    }
```

And here is my Closing Event in my child window:

```
        private void Window_HBD_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WINDOWS-B1AT5HC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CustomerRelations;Integrated Security=True;");

        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [hb_Disputes] SET FR_DSP_CLSF=@FR_DSP_CLSF, FR_CUST_CNTCT=@FR_CUST_CNTCT, FR_WRK_REQ=@FR_WRK_REQ, FR_OPN_ERR=@FR_OPN_ERR, FR_SO_TP=@FR_SO_TP, FR_SO_DTLS=@FR_SO_DTLS, FR_CMMNT=@FR_CMMNT, FR_SO_DT_WNTD=@FR_SO_DT_WNTD, FINADJ=@FINADJ, SERTYPE=@SERTYPE, CALLRSN=@CALLRSN, SECCAUSE=@SECCAUSE, MTR=@MTR, RPTTYPE=@RPTTYPE, PRMCAUSE=@PRMCAUSE, COMMENT=@COMMENT, FR_TS_LATESTUPD=@FR_TS_LATESTUPD WHERE DSP_ID=@DSP_ID", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DSP_ID", txt_RowRecrd.Text);

            // Second Row
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FR_DSP_CLSF", cmb_DisputeClassification.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FR_CUST_CNTCT", cmb_CustomerContact.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FR_WRK_REQ", cmb_requestedwork.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FR_OPN_ERR", cmb_OpenInError.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FR_SO_TP", cmb_ServiceOrderType.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FR_SO_DTLS", cmb_ServiceOrderDetails.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FR_CMMNT", txt_ReviewNotes.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FR_SO_DT_WNTD", DatePicker_ScheduledFor.Text);

            // Third Row
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RPTTYPE", cmb_UtilityRptTyp.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FINADJ", cmb_FinancialAdjustment.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SERTYPE", cmb_ServiceTypeAdjustment.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CALLRSN", cmb_InitialCallReason.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRMCAUSE", cmb_PrimCause.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SECCAUSE", cmb_UnderlyingCause.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MTR", cmb_MeterIssue.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COMMENT", txt_ResolutionNotes.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FR_TS_LATESTUPD", DateTime.Now);
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@FR_TS_LATESTUPD", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.UtcNow;



            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in several ways, here I explain two ways:

1. Implement a custom event in your child window, something like "AfterClosingEvent". This event will fire in its closing event in the child window and you can invoke it under specific circumstances. In the main window, define a subscriber for this event and implement it according to your logic.

Code in your child window:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window {
    public Window1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event EventHandler<string> AfterClosingEvent;

    private void Window1_OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
        // Logic for your database update...

        this.AfterClosingEvent?.Invoke(this, this.TextBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

Code in your parent window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OpenWindow_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        var windowToOpen = new Window1();
        windowToOpen.AfterClosingEvent += (o, s) => {
            this.TextBlock1.Text = s;
        };
        windowToOpen.Show();
    }
}
```

2. You don't really need to implement a custom event in your child window. You only define a custom event if you need to trigger the event under specific circumstances, and not just after the window is closing. If you need to execute logic ***whenever*** the child window is closing, you just need to subscribe to the Window.Closing event in the parent window, like this:

   ```
   windowToOpen.Closing += (o, args) => {};
   ```

I leave a project demo in [this](https://github.com/marlonedu/WpfTests/tree/master/WpfApp12) site.

Comment: This is very good but it doesn't work. The issue is I don't have `Textboxes` and `Comboboxes` in my parent window. I have a `DataGrid` so it has to return there. Should this still work and I am just missing something?

Comment: I don't understand why a DataGrid instead of other UI element change the idea of the response. To understand you better, please could you upload a demo in GitHub or other repository?

Comment: I would be difficult to do that because it is connected to my SQL Server local database where the data is being pulled. But in my example, I have `DataGridData()`  in `Window1` that I would like to call when `Window2` closes.